# Могут ли быть слова «истец — исток» и «отец — отток» однокоренными?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Могут ли быть слова ***истец — исток*** и ***отец — отток*** однокоренными?

По аналогии с другими группами слов:
канатоходец — ходок;
тунеядец — едок;
венец — венок;
трезубец — зубок;
сучец — сучок;
цветец — цветок;
стрелец — стрелок.

Comment: корень слова **истец -> иск**, однокоренное слово **искать**, в то время как в слове **исток** корень - **ток**, а **ис** - приставка, однокоренные глаголы **истекать** и **источать**, разница между словами **отец** и **отток** скорей всего аналогична, во всяком случае очевидно что **отток** раскладывается на **от + ток**, **отец** же, по всей видимости состоит из корня (праслав. *оtьсь из *оtьkъ)... но возможно однокоренными с ним являются приставка и предлог **от** как обозначение источника или начала

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка истец <— ист(ый) и т. д.

Comment: @Aer OK, не претендую на **ист**ину

Comment: @Aer выходит что **иск** и **поиск** или **иск** и  **истец** - это разнокоренные слова?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка иск и истец — слова с разными корнями.

Comment: @Aer ОК, любопытно

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка не знаю имеет ли это значение или нет, но в судебнике 1497 года истец назывался ищея